# Logistic regression vs. ordinal logistic regression, which one to use?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit

I am quite puzzled by the logistic regression results with three outcome categories `(0,1,2)`; `0 is no feelings, 1 is slightly happy, 2 is extremely happy`.

I tried both (1) logistic regression and ordered the outcome (2) using ordinal logistic regression through `MASS::polr`

The summary from `(1)` looks like this:

```
     Call:
glm(formula = FeelingOutcome ~ Dosage + Age + factor(Sex.x) + 
    factor(Race.x) + TestPeriod, family = binomial, data = TestSet, 
    na.action = "na.exclude")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.7767  -1.1058   0.6135   1.0088   2.0481  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)          1.457e+01  1.455e+03   0.010   0.9920  
Dosage              -1.981e+00  8.145e-01  -2.433   0.0150 *
Age                  4.434e-02  2.494e-02   1.778   0.0755 .
factor(Sex.x)Male    6.504e-01  4.544e-01   1.431   0.1523  
factor(Race.x)Black -1.670e+01  1.455e+03  -0.011   0.9908  
factor(Race.x)White -1.513e+01  1.455e+03  -0.010   0.9917  
TestPeriod          -1.413e-04  1.319e-04  -1.072   0.2839  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 146.34  on 105  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 130.71  on  99  degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 144.71

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 14
```

The statistics showed moderate significance of Dosage association with Feeling Outcome.

However, when I use ordinal logistic regression, the strange number showed:

```
  TestORdinalLR <- MASS::polr(FeelingOutcome ~ Dosage + 
                                     Age + 
                                     factor(Sex.x) +
                                     factor(Race.x) + 
                                      TestPeriod, 
                                   data=TestSet, Hess = TRUE, na.action = "na.exclude")
ctable <- coef(summary(TestORdinalLR))
p_OrdiDxSHCec <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p_OrdiDxSHCec)
    > ctable
                                  Value   Std. Error      t value       p value
Dosage              -1.270935e+00 0.0948121344  -13.4047742  5.669557e-41
Age                  3.844785e-02 0.0138925651    2.7675126  5.648587e-03
factor(Sex.x)Male    1.799269e-01 0.3784498549    0.4754313  6.344796e-01
factor(Race.x)Black -1.670944e+01 0.3947162775  -42.3327766  0.000000e+00
factor(Race.x)White -1.536035e+01 0.4342894383  -35.3689268 5.131513e-274
TestPeriod          -4.578557e-05 0.0003773869   -0.1213226  9.034355e-01
0|1                 -1.432219e+01 0.0395987756 -361.6826279  0.000000e+00
1|2                 -1.365826e+01 0.1579986481  -86.4454177  0.000000e+00
```

I saw a whopping p-value change from `0.0150` to `5.669557e-41`. Intuitively, I know I should use ordinal logistic regression, but from the results, the logistic regression seems more realistic?

Here's the data distribution (I flipped the x and y for visualization):
[image]

Comment: DId you discretize the outcome somehow for your logistic regression? You didn't mention it. I would've expected it to error if you tried lgoistic regression with FeelingOutcome that has values outside of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What’s wrong with such a low p-value? We usually hope for low p-values.

Comment: What do you mean "the logistic regression seems more realistic"?

Comment: @bdeonovic I did not discretize the outcome, there were three outcomes.

Comment: @bdeonovic I thought the p-value was not representative of what I saw from the distribution of the data. .. and thought it was not realistic

Comment: @Dave thank you! I've been lurking around Cross Validated a lot for answers, but due to no statistical training, I dare not to ask any question till I am desperate. lol

Comment: p-values are not measures of effect and also not appropriate to compare across different models. I'm still not sure how you fit a logistic regression with an outcome which takes on multiple values...

Comment: A `glm` model with `family=binomial` will fit a logistic regression with two outcome levels only, not three outcome levels.

Comment: @SalMangiafico, thank you for pointing this out. But why didn't I get any error message from R?

Comment: @bdeonovic I did not know that glm can only take two different outcomes... and I am surprised that I did not get a warning or error message from it.

Comment: What is your reference level for `factor(Race.x)`? You show coefficients for both `Black` and `White`, so the reference level presumably has relatively few members in your data. You didn't get an error in binomial logistic regression because, as the help page says, "the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success)." Your outcome was presumably interpreted as a factor.

Comment: I don't know why there isn't a warning.  ... It appears that if there are more than two levels in the dependent variable, that `glm(family=binomal)` will use the first level as the first level, and all other levels as the second level.

Comment: but all of the above conversation is beside the point; you should address concerns regarding model selection (ordinal vs logistic (after grouping categories 1 and 2)) via model fit statistics not by looking at the p-value of dosage.

Comment: @bdeonovic I agree. Can I rephrase the question in the original post to.. how to select between multivariable logistic regression vs ordinal logistic regression?

Comment: I will read through some posts on that before I do anything else. For now, I think the question I asked is solved, it's pretty obvious to all of you that `family=binomial` in `glm` should only have two outcomes. Anything more than three should be multivariable or ordinal, and I will study a bit to see if I need more help. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick check, ensure the variable is a ordered factor using str(TestSet). I do not know if this would be a problem for the polr function or not.

I think you may be using the analysis from here: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/. If not then it is a good resource and explains things well. Their data set is bigger than yours, thus the manual p-value calculation you have done may be less satisfactory on your data set.

From the webpage: “One way to calculate a p-value in this case is by comparing the t-value against the standard normal distribution, like a z test. Of course this is only true with infinite degrees of freedom, but is reasonably approximated by large samples, becoming increasingly biased as sample size decreases.”.

The calculation you did for p-values matches theirs. However, your lower sample size means your p-values will be biased to be low.

Unless you have done so already checking the proportional odds assumption is worth doing. Per the webpage section proportional odds assumption: “One of the assumptions underlying ordinal logistic (and ordinal probit) regression is that the relationship between each pair of outcome groups is the same. In other words, ordinal logistic regression assumes that the coefficients that describe the relationship between, say, the lowest versus all higher categories of the response variable are the same as those that describe the relationship between the next lowest category and all higher categories, etc. This is called the proportional odds assumption or the parallel regression assumption. Because the relationship between all pairs of groups is the same, there is only one set of coefficients.”.

How to go about this is also detailed.

Hope this helps.